# vimscript autocmd passing a argument to a function

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to run tags upon file save. But I can't get the current buffers name inside the function, I need this after the write, since I want ctags to process the new amendments. Ideally I want to pass the . argument into the function from the autocmd

```
 23 function! UpdateTagsIfHasTags()
 24     echom "adsfsdf"
 25     return
 26     let tagsPath = printf('%s/tags', expand("%:h"))
 27     if !empty(glob(tagsPath))
 28         system(printf('/usr/local/bin/phpctags %s', filepath))
 29     endif
 30 endfunction
 31 augroup tags
 32     autocmd!
 33     autocmd BufEnter *.tex silent! !start /min ctags *.tex
 34     autocmd BufEnter *.php :call UpdateTagsIfHasTags()
 35 augroup END
```

How can I pass the current file path to the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can get autocmd file name with special variables `<afile>` or `<amatch>`. See `:h expand`, `:h <afile>`, `:h <amatch>` for details.

```
function! Update()
  echom expand('<afile>')
  echom expand('<amatch>')
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter *.vim :call Update()
```